# Ask password at login on Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, users, login, password

When I installed Linux Mint Cinnamon on my machine the first time, I checked the box saying something like `don't ask for password when logging in`.
Now I would like to revert this option, but I can't find any solution.
I tried removing my user from the `nopasswordlogin` group, but it didn't work.

[image: User and Goups]

Comment: What does `grep login /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` return?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by commenting (writing `#` before the line) the line saying `autologin-user=something` in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.